# Cookie not being created (not a schoolboy error, I hope)

Tags: 7, cookies

I'm building a deeplink system into a very complex website which needs cookies and other context set-up before the deeplink will work (otherwise the page gets redirected back to the home page - not much use).

So I've added a module which provides the deeplink entry point through hook_menu:

```
deeplink/<deeplink-parameters>
```

The callback builds the context, adds the cookies and then redirects to the actual required page.

So much for the theory. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why not.

In order to replicate a completely "virgin" request I've been using incognito windows, restarting the server and clearing caches before each test. In the test version I'm not redirecting to a new page, just outputting a line of text to display the page.

But even attempting to generate a simple test cookie with a long life (REQUEST_TIME + 999999) fails. No cookie created. The setcookie() function is returning TRUE (cookie created), which implies there is no problem.

The only cookies I can see are the ones created by JavaScript on the page itself, and a couple created by the Zeus wrapper (there are no Zeus rules to delete cookies on standard Drupal pages).

Just in case the cookie isn't visible on the first page I am also then moving to another page but still no cookie. Seems like it just isn't being created despite what the function says.

Additional data: There is also no PHP Session ID cookie.

Any thoughts as to why the cookies are not appearing?

EDIT: Looking at this further, I moved the setcookie() function into index.php (before the Drupal bootstrap), and it still wasn't creating the cookie.

So rather than issuing the deeplink command as above I simply went to the home page. And it's *still* not creating the cookie (as an anonymous user, with everything cleared before we start).

Only when I moved away and into the more complex part of the site did the test cookie appear. At the same time that the PHP Session ID cookie appeared. Is this a hidden dependency? No cookies can be created through PHP unless there's a PHP session ID?

Comment: It would help if you could show the code you are using to set the cookie ;)

Comment: setcookie('test', 'test', time() + 99999);

I spent all of yesterday working through a zillion different options and scenarios. Putting the setcookie() in various places in the code, including outside of a function so it got executed immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The world has not turned upside-down.

It turned out that Zeus was indeed eating cookies of anonymous accesses, I had to go through every Zeus rule (we have a lot) until I found it.

Testing with Zeus bypassed demonstrated the cookies were created correctly.

*Bloody Greek Gods, wandering in uninvited and eating all the cookies...*